# Set data grouping

Tags: highcharts

On a candlestick chart, I have oclh values at minutes rsolution.

I'd like to be able to programmatically set the grouping range (1min, 5min, 15min, 30min, 1h, 2h, 4h, 8h, 12h, 1w, 1m, 1y).

Is it possible directly using highcharts? Or should I rely on a ochl manipulation library and is there such a library?

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Comment: Thanks, but not very explicit... Should I force and set the desired grouping as the only option in the units array?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to format the series range via the [**`rangeSelector`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector).

## type

Defines the timespan, can be one of 'millisecond', 'second', 'minute', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'ytd' (year to date), 'year' and 'all'.

## count

Defines how many units of the defined type to use.

## text

The text for the button itself.

## Usage

```
 rangeSelector: {
        enabled: true,
        buttons: [{
            type: 'minute',
            count: 1,
            text: '1min'
        }, {
            type: 'minute',
            count: 5,
            text: '5min'
        }, {
            type: 'minute',
            count: 60,
            text: '1hr'
        }, {
            type: 'week',
            count: 1,
            text: '1w'
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: '1m'
        }, {
            type: 'year',
            count: 1,
            text: '1y'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }]
    }
```

[**`Fiddled`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/h5sSR/2/) example.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for range manipulation... rather data point grouping. For example: I have intraday values (every minute) and what to consolidate by groups of 5min, 10min, 15min, or 1h.